# Factorygirl reuse association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

Here I have two factories defined, Post and User where User is associated with Post. I'm using this to seed a database (not a test).

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    username { Faker::Internet.user_name }
    password { Faker::Internet.password(12) }
    email { Faker::Internet.email }
  end

  factory :post do
    title { Faker::Lorem.sentence(5) }
    url { Faker::Internet.url }
    description { Faker::Lorem.sentences(2, word_count=9).join(" ").first(90) }
    user
  end
end
```

And 100 times I create a post.

```
FactoryGirl.create_list(:post, 100)
```

**Question:**

This creates 100 posts and it also creates 100 users. One Post per User. How can I tell `Factorygirl` to create 9 Users (i.e. just something less than 100, 9 just an example) and split the 100 Posts between them? Ideally I'd like to go to User#show page and see more than 1 Post.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something similar to this:

```
users= FactoryGirl.create_list(:user, 10)

total_random_posts_count = 0
users.each do |user|
    random_post_count = rand(1..10)
    total_random_posts_count += random_post_count
    FactoryGirl.create_list(:post, random_post_count, user: user )
end
FactoryGirl.create_list(:post, 100 - total_random_posts_count , user: user )
```

Comment: also - `users[rand(10)]` could also be `users.sample`

Comment: This randomly samples 1 User out of the 10 and assigns that User to all 100 posts. 

I am looking for a way for FactoryGirl to choose a random associated User (out of a pool of 10) EACH TIME and a post is created.